# System.Object found in more than one assembly

Tags: c#, .net, exception

I've a strange problem at the moment where i sometimes get the following exception:

Type System.Object found in more than one assembly (mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, ... and System.Runtime, Version=4.0.0.0, ...)

The app is a classic desktop app which references .NET 4.5 but the main problem is that this only happens sometimes so it's really hard to reproduce.

I think that it allways works if System.Runtime gets not loaded.
But how can figure out who is responsible for loading System.Runtime? Why is this assembly beeing loaded sometimes?

UPDATE:
I think the problem is this assembly: Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform This assembly internally loads System.Runtime via: Assembly.Load("System.Runtime, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a").Location;
But i've no idea how to solve this problem.

Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: Exception or compile-time error? That sounds more like a compile-time error... and it sounds like something you'll see if you try to add a reference to a PCL or similar.

Comment: I have also encountered this not so much in the past in VS17, restarting VS usually fixed this.

Comment: No it's a runtime error. Compiling works fine.

Comment: I think the problem is this assembly:
Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform
This assembly internally loads System.Runtime via:
Assembly.Load("System.Runtime, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a").Location;
But i've no idea how to solve this problem.